# ® symbol not being parsed in JSON-LD. Backslash(/) doesn't work

Tags: schema, microdata, json-ld, html-escape-characters, structured-data

So I'm currently uploading a website schema and it has thrown up some parsing errors in a string. The ® symbol is showing up as shown below. However, adding a backslash does not seem to work and is still throwing up an error on Google's Structured Data Testing tool.

For example:
'''"name": "What is ___Secure®?",'''
This throws up the error shown.

[image]

But even when I add a backslash as an escape character, it doesn't show properly, as shown.

[image]

What is the way out of this?

Thanks.

Comment: What tool is throwing the parsing errors? By error, do you mean it shows a different character? Your second image shows a forward slash. ® is not a character that needs escaping with a backslash anyhow. But it does need the right character set.

Comment: Use unicode: `\u00AE` see: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00AE/index.htm